# Embed key-values in key-values using expl3

Tags: expl3

I'm trying to embed key-values in key-values in a call like the following:

```latex
\showchapter{
    title=My chapter,
    authors={
        {name=Peter,affiliation=MIT},
        {name=Mary,affiliation=UCLA},
    },
}
```

to have this output

```
My chapter
    Peter, MIT
    Mary, UCLA
```

But I cannot access the embedded key-values `authors`.

The call to `\seq_map_indexed_function:NN \authors \callshowauthorx:nn` in `\showauthors` doesn't work as expected.

In the following example I just want to output the arguments and the embedded arguments:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { authorkeys }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \name,
    affiliation .tl_set:N = \affiliation,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showauthor}{m}
  {
    \textbf{showauthor:~} 
    \keys_set:nn { authorkeys } { #1 }
    ( \name { ,~ } \affiliation )
  }
```

```latex
\seq_new:N \myseqx
\NewDocumentCommand \showauthors { m }
  {
    \textbf{showauthors:~} 
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \myseqx { #1 }
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \myseqx \callshowauthorx:nn
  }
\cs_new:Nn \callshowauthorx:nn
  { \par \showauthor{#2} }
```

```latex
\keys_define:nn { chapterkeys }
  {
    title .tl_set:N = \title,
    authors .clist_set:N = \authors,
  }
\seq_new:N \myseqy
\NewDocumentCommand{\showchapter}{m}
  {
    \keys_set:nn { chapterkeys } { #1 }
    \par\textbf{showchapter-title:~}
    \title
    \par\textbf{showchapter-authors:~}
    % next line seems not to work as expected
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \authors \callshowauthorx:nn
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

```latex
\begin{document}

\showauthor{name=Peter,affiliation=MIT}

\showauthors{
    {name=Peter,affiliation=MIT},
    {name=Mary,affiliation=UCLA},
}

\showchapter{
    title=My chapter,
    authors={
        {name=Peter,affiliation=MIT},
        {name=Mary,affiliation=UCLA},
    },
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please follow the naming convention. Your seq should be called e.g. \l_wolf_myseqx_seq, and similar for your commands. And also your keys should use a module name.

Comment: \@UlrikeFischer: I would very much like to follow the naming conventions. But for the time beeing I'm not sure if I understand the type, the argument especification, the level of organisation of code etc. I should use. Therefore I avoid them because otherwise I would have a mess of wrong named variables which would make it more confusing. BTW: Why is expl3, specially interface3.pdf soooooo lacking of examples?

Comment: interface3 is not a tutorial, it's a reference document of every interface, extracted from the source, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expl3 has over a thousand posts with expl3 examples

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle: Yes. I am aware. Generated documentation from source not always follows the concepts behind literate programming. I've dedicated the last five days to understand how this works. And no offense but to me it feels like the authors are not interested into attract new adepts. I am very happy that at least the community here in TeX.EX (you included) is friendly and willing to help. Thanks to you all.

Comment: wolfrevo, you do realise @DavidCarlisle *is* one of the authors? So is Ulrike Fischer ....

Comment: I've partially fixed your code, but there are places where I don't understand what you're trying to do. The design seems inside out in some places: that is, you're using `\NewDocumentCommand` to create commands you then use inside things created with `\cs_new...` and I don't know what the purpose is. `\callshowauthorx:nn` just discards its first argument? I think I understand what `\showchapter` is meant to do, so that bit works. But if `\showauthors` does something very similar, why not use a common command?

Comment: \@cfr Actually what I'm trying to do is to access the value of a key `authors` which is a list of key-values as given in `\showchapter{ ..., authors={{name=Peter,affiliation=MIT},{name=Mary,affiliation=UCLA}},...}` and then to iterate the author keys (name, affiliation). I guess that I'm using a wrong key property type for `authors` and that I do not properly convert `authors` to something to iterate and extract its key-values.

Comment: \@cfr I've updated my question to show the needed output.

Comment: you misunderstood my point. interface3 is a dictionary not an encyclopedia. it does not lack examples because it is poorly generated, it lacks them by design.  saying the latex project don't understand literate programming is quite amusing really:)

Comment: I apologize if my comment offended someone. I really didn't mean to. I simply was expressing my frustration for not being able to find documentation (and this is exclusively my fault!). And you're right: nobody can learn a language by reading a dictionary. The best way to learn a language is probably total immersion and talking with native/proficient speakers. And that is what TeX.sx offers. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it very much.

Comment: @wolfrevo your comment wasn't offensive, just wrong:-)

Comment: your example is not so long that you can't try to follow the naming convention, and if you get it wrong, someone will correct you. But not trying at all is not a good idea as you will very soon produce confusing code or code that clashes with some other package if you use ad-hoc generic names.

Comment: \@Thanks for your wise advice. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you actually want all of this machinery. I take it some is for testing/development.

I've tidied up the code (a bit) and modified it to do what I think you want it to do. Perhaps it will prove helpful and you can fine tune it.

I would stick to `clist`s here, rather than using sequences (`seq`). The latter have advantages and they are necessary for some things, but they add a layer of complexity when you're trying to get to grips with `expl3` and you can do everything you want with `clist`s and token lists (`tl`s). They're also one step closer to user input and I just think it is easier to start with fewer types of thing until you get familiar with the syntax.

In your original code, you seem to be mixing up `clist` with `seq` and/or `tl`. One advantage of the naming convention is it makes it harder to do this and easier to spot.

If you say

```
\tl_new:N <blah>
```

you're making a token list and `<blah>` should end `_tl`. Similarly

```
\clist_new:N <blah>_clist
```

and so on for the other variables (i.e. not commands, but sequences and the rest).

Variables should always start `\l_` or `\g_` and constants `\c_`. Generally, you want `\l_` for a local variable or `\g_` for a global one. I typically use local unless I need global.

We also need a module name. I've used `wolfrevo`. Then, the form for a local variable name is basically

```
\l_wolfrevo_<description>_<type>
```

To handle the embedded authors, you need to set two lots of keys. The most straightforward method is just to pass the contents of `authors` from the chapter on and set the next level of keys.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\showchapter}{m}
{
  \keys_set:nn { wolfrevo / chapterkeys } { #1 }
```

We put the value of `authors` into a `clist`, `\l_wolfrevo_authors_clist`, and title into a token list (`tl`), `\g_wolfrevo_title_tl`.

```
  \par\textbf{showchapter-title:~}
  \g_wolfrevo_title_tl
```

All we want is to typeset the title, so we do that.

```
  \par\textbf{showchapter-authors:~}
```

The authors we don't want to use directly. Rather, we want to treat the contents of the clist as itself a set of keys, this time passing them to the `authorkeys` stuff for processing. We can just map the clist to another internal function for this purpose.

```
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_wolfrevo_authors_clist
  {
    \wolfrevo_showauthor:n { ##1 }
  }
}
```

`\wolfrevo_showauthor:n` then sets the keys and typesets the name and affiliation for each author.

I've not put any attempt to sanity check the input, so you'll get weird errors if you pass the commands anything unexpected. If you're sharing the code with other people (including a later you), you might want to build some meaningful feedback in.

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { wolfrevo / authorkeys }
{
  name .tl_set:N = \l_wolfrevo_name_tl,
  name .initial:n = {Bilbo ~ Baggins},
  affiliation .tl_set:N = \l_wolfrevo_affiliation_tl,
  affiliation .initial:n = {Hobbinton ~ College ~ of ~ Further ~ Education, ~ The ~ Shire},
}
\keys_define:nn { wolfrevo / chapterkeys }
{
  title .tl_gset:N = \g_wolfrevo_title_tl,
  title .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  authors .clist_set:N = \l_wolfrevo_authors_clist,
  authors .initial:n = {},
}
\clist_new:N \l_wolfrevo_tmpa_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_showauthor:nn
{
  \textbf{showauthor:~} (#1 , ~ #2)
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \wolfrevo_showauthor:nn { VV } 
\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_showauthor:n
{
  \keys_set:nn { wolfrevo / authorkeys } { #1 }
  \wolfrevo_showauthor:VV \l_wolfrevo_name_tl \l_wolfrevo_affiliation_tl
  \par  
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showchapter}{m}
{
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { wolfrevo / chapterkeys } { #1 }
    \par
    \textbf{showchapter-title:~} \g_wolfrevo_title_tl
    \par
    \textbf{showchapter-authors:~}
    \par
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_wolfrevo_authors_clist
    {
      \wolfrevo_showauthor:n { ##1 }
    }
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  
\showchapter{%
  title=Prequel,
}

\showchapter{
  title=My chapter,
  authors={
    {name=Peter,affiliation=MIT},
    {name=Mary,affiliation=UCLA},
  },
}

\showchapter{%
  title=Sequel,
}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully, the following is something akin to your target.

[image: typesetting with two rounds of keys]

### Edit

What I usually do is use a group to keep changes local. That way, you always get the initial value of keys if nothing is specified. That's not what you want in every case, but it is quite a common setup.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\showchapter}{m}
{
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { wolfrevo / chapterkeys } { #1 }
  \par\textbf{showchapter-title:~}
  \l_wolfrevo_title_tl
  \par\textbf{showchapter-authors:~}
  % next line seems not to work as expected
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_wolfrevo_authors_clist
  {
    \wolfrevo_showauthor:n { ##1 }
  }
  \group_end:
}
```

But note that this will make the title local, too. You could prevent that by using

```
  title .tl_gset:N = \g_wolfrevo_title_tl,
```

and substituting `\g_wolfrevo_title_tl` for `\l_wolfrevo_title_tl`. That way, the title would survive the group (for use in headers, say), but the list of authors would not.

These changes are now implemented in the code above.

Comment: \@cfr Thank you very much! That really helps. BTW omitting arguments outputs the initial values (Bilbo etc.) only on the first call. Posterior calls output the last set value.

Comment: @wolfrevo Yes. What I usually do is put `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` to keep the changes local. That way, you always get the initial values if nothing is specified. You could also just make the initial values empty if you're worried about Hobbits popping up in unexpected places.

Comment: @wolfrevo See edit.

Comment: \@cfr Thanks again. I've deleted some unnecessary and confusing lines of my original code in your answer. That way future readers won't be confused.

Comment: @wolfrevo I've tidied up in a slightly different way. I think it is good to have `.initial:n` values unless you want to generate an error if something isn't set. `.default:n` does something different. It gets used if you use the key but don't give a value. It's useful for conditionals, but I'm not sure it makes sense here.

Comment: \@cfr. Yes. I've read the different logic of `initial` and `default`. For my special case I need `value_required` which probably makes `initial` and `default` redundant

Comment: @wolfrevo In that case, I would just use `.tl_set:N` or whatever alone and test to see if the variable is empty after the keys are set. Requiring a value will, so far as I know, only require a value if the key is used. It won't complain if the key is omitted.

Comment: \@cfr. Oh I see. Thanks again.